# Include results from a PHP file in another file without messing up object references?

Tags: php, oop

Apologies if I explain this badly and it doesn't make sense, I'm a little confused.

I'd like to be able to include the output of a PHP file within another in a given place, and to do that, I'm using the buffer and include/require:

```
 if (file_exists(CUSTOM_PHP_DIR."/".$filename)) {
   ob_start();
   include(CUSTOM_PHP_DIR."/".$filename);
   $html = ob_get_clean();
 }
 echo $html; //where I want the results to go.
```

The problem is, I've included the above in a method of a class; so when the file includes - `$this` contains the properties and methods of the class that did the include, which completely breaks what's in the include, which was this:

```
myClass::getSomethingFromDatabase();
```

I understand that it breaks myClass is an extension from a database class which call on itself as `$this` to do a bunch of stuff, and $this is now a reference to a different class that included the file.

I've worked around the problem for the time being by instantiating the object I want to use in the include, which required database credentials:

```
$newObject = new myClass(DB_CREDENTIALS);
$newObject->getSomethingFromDatabase();
```

I've had to `define` the database credentials as constants to pick them up quickly and easily and I'd wanted to avoid doing that.  Have I missed a better way I can just make the static call work?

Comment: So before I answer, am I right in that what you really are after for this is elimination of code duplication for a particular often repeated database call?  It kind of sounds like this second class needs to extend the first if that's the case.

Comment: Not so much code duplication as object duplication, I shouldn't have to create another instance of $newObject, because I still have a database object.  The method of myClass that I'm calling in turn calls another method via $this->doSomething() to run the query, but $this is now a completely different object (the one which actually included the file) which is nothing to do with the database...

Comment: To summarize: `$this` is in scope in the include, and that's the problem as far as I can see it?

Comment: Yep, it is [exactly as the documentation states](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) (_" $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object)."_), and as far as I know, there are No Known Cures... `unset`, `extract`, all fail to make a dent. It's not pretty, but you'd either have to live with it, or avoid calling the includes from an object context.

Comment: On the other hand, you should of course have no reference to `$this` in static methods...

Comment: Yeah, I thought of a few different ways around it - I just wondered if I was missing something.  Evidently not.  Thanks for confirming :-)

Comment: Re your other comment, you're right - $this was obviously not coming from the static method, rather it was coming from the object that called it, which also knew about the database object.  I guess it was a happy accident that it was working the way it was...!

Comment: @Codecraft: The way you do it seems a bit complicated. Why don't you just pass the reference to your $newObject into your class if an instance already exists? Can you elaborate what's in the file you are including?

Comment: @Dan It probably is; tricky one to explain but the class that's including the file doesn't usually need db connection & doesn't get passed one. Its a tag translator (like BB code); stripping HTML and converting custom tags into specific styled elements. One of the tags allows you to specify a PHP file so that you can include the results, in this particular file, its just some info from a database table. The 'frontend' of the site has a DB, it calls the tag-translator (without passing the DB as its not usually needed), but the code being included happens to need the DB on occasion.

Comment: What I should probably do is write a quick method to allow you to pass in a DB to the code translator so its there if needed.

Comment: Seems to be the more elegant version to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to understand from the comments that you have refactored your code another way, however the answer to your original question was to do your include in a new function context, to discard every variable in the scope

As you can see in the following examples, anonymous_include() seems to do what you want.

```
$ php test.php
Another class
bar
--
Direct include
$this exists
--
Anonymous include
$this does not exists
```

test.php:

```
<?php                                                                                  
class main                                                                             
{                                                                                      
  public function another_class()                                                      
  {                                                                                    
    $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/include.php';                                          

    if (!file_exists($path)) {                                                         
      die('The file does not exists :(');                                              
    }                                                                                  

    ob_start();                                                                        
    include($path);                                                                    
    $html = ob_get_clean();                                                            
    echo $html;                                                                        
  }                                                                                    

  public function direct_include()                                                     
  {                                                                                    
    $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/include_2.php';                                        

    if (!file_exists($path)) {                                                         
      die('The file does not exists :(');                                              
    }                                                                                  

    ob_start();                                                                        
    include($path);                                                                    
    $html = ob_get_clean();                                                            
    echo $html;                                                                        
  }                                                                                    

  public function anonymous_include()                                                  
  {                                                                                    
    $include = function() {                                                            
      $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/include_2.php';                                      

      if (!file_exists($path)) {                                                       
        die('The file does not exists :(');                                            
      }                                                                                

      ob_start();                                                                      
      include($path);                                                                  
      $html = ob_get_clean();                                                          
      return $html;                                                                    
    };                                                                                 
    echo $include();                                                                   
  }                                                                                    
}                                                                                      

$main = new main();                                                                    

echo "Another class\n";                                                                

$main->another_class(); // $this exists, but things seems to work fine                        

echo "--\nDirect include\n";                                                           

$main->direct_include(); // $this exists                                        

echo "--\nAnonymous include\n";             

$main->anonymous_include(); // $this exists
```

include.php:

```
<?php
class sub
{
  protected
    $foo = 'bar';

  public function foobar()
  {
    echo $this->foo."\n";
  }
}

$sub = new sub();
$sub->foobar();
```

include_2.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($this)) {
  echo "\$this exists\n";
} else {
  echo "\$this does not exists\n";
}
```